# Convergence of series with iterated $\ln$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let us consider two function $\textrm{pln}_1\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\textrm{pln}_2\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$:

$$\textrm{pln}_1(n) = n\cdot\ln n\cdot\ln\ln n\cdots\underbrace{\ln\circ\ln\circ\cdots\circ\ln n}_{\text{one time less than it is possible}};$$

and

$$\textrm{pln}_2(n) = n\cdot\ln n\cdot\ln\ln n\cdots\underbrace{\ln\circ\ln\circ\cdots\circ\ln n}_{\text{two times less than it is possible}}.$$

For example:

$$\textrm{pln}_1(1) = 1;$$
$$\textrm{pln}_1(5) = 5\cdot\ln 5\cdot\ln\ln5;$$
$$\textrm{pln}_2(5) = 5\cdot\ln 5;$$
$$\textrm{pln}_1(15) = 15\cdot \ln 15\cdot\ln\ln 15;$$
$$\textrm{pln}_1(16) = 16\cdot \ln 16\cdot\ln\ln 16\cdot\ln\ln\ln 16;$$
$$\textrm{pln}_2(16) = 16\cdot \ln 16\cdot\ln\ln 16.$$

What can we say about convergence of the following series:

$$S_1=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\textrm{pln}_1(n)}?$$

$$S_2=\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\textrm{pln}_2(n)}?$$

Comment: Just to clarify: by "one time less than it is possible", is your intent that the last factor is always $>0$, or that the last factor is always $>1$?  As currently written ($>0$), that may raise some questions about Diophantine approximation which seem to be separate from the question of rate of growth.  Both questions are interesting, but I'm speculating that maybe you care more about the latter?

Comment: @ErickWong I clarified my question :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I now believe it can be shown that the first sum (with $\ln_1$) diverges, so the second sum seems more interesting :).

Comment: I think I have a solution for the second one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the first sum diverges!  Define the iterated exponential sequence $a_0=1, a_{n+1} = e^{a_n}$.  I'm not sure that it's known whether $a_k = \exp(\exp(\exp(\exp(\cdots\exp(1)\cdots)$ is always a non-integer (for $k>0$), but I'm going to assume it is, and this argument only requires minor adjustments otherwise.

Let $b_k = \lceil a_k \rceil$ for $k>0$ and let's examine the value of $\text{pln}_1(b_k)$, which by assumption will be exactly

$$b_k \ln b_k \ln\ln b_k \cdots \underbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}_{\text{$k+1$ times}}\; b_k.$$

Clearly $b_k > a_k$, $\ln b_k > \ln a_k$, $\ln \ln b_k > \ln \ln a_k$ and so on for each iterated logarithm.  So let's get an upper bound on the differences $\ln b_k - \ln a_k$ and so forth:

$$\begin{align}
b_k &< a_k + 1, \\
\ln b_k &< \ln(a_k + 1) = \ln a_k + \ln(1 + a_k^{-1}) < a_{k-1} + a_k^{-1}, \\
\ln \ln b_k &< \ln(a_{k-1} + a_k^{-1}) = \ln a_{k-1} + \ln(1 + (a_{k-1}a_k)^{-1}) < a_{k-2} + (a_{k-1} a_k)^{-1},
\end{align}$$

You can see an inductive pattern forming, which eventually leads to:

$$
\begin{align}
\underbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}_{\text{$k$ times}}\; b_k &< a_0 + (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k)^{-1} = 1 + (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k)^{-1}, \\
\underbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}_{\text{$k+1$ times}}\; b_k &< (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k)^{-1}.\\
\end{align}
$$

So then $$\text{pln}_1(b_k) < \frac{b_k \ln b_k \ln \ln b_k \cdots \overbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}^{\text{$k$ times}}\; b_k}{a_k \ln a_k \ln \ln a_k \cdots \underbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}_{\text{$k$ times}}\; a_k},$$

which we can prove from the above bounds is very close to $1$.  Indeed, the above calculations let us bound the absolute difference of logs of the numerator and denominator by:

$$a_k^{-1} + (a_k a_{k-1})^{-1} + \cdots + (a_k a_{k-1} \cdots a_1)^{-1} < k/a_k,$$

which converges to $0$ very quickly as $k \to\infty$.  It follows that $\text{pln}_1(b_k)$ is bounded below by a positive constant close to $1$, so that $\sum_n  1/\text{pln}_1(n)$ diverges.

In fact, heuristically we expect the difference $\lceil a_k \rceil - a_k$ to be randomly distributed in $(0,1)$, in particular it should get arbitrarily close to $0$.  So it's extremely plausible (albeit hopeless to prove) that $\text{pln}_1(n)$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$, meaning $\limsup_{n\to\infty} 1/\text{pln}_1(n) = +\infty$.

We can also show the second sum diverges by a similar calculation.  Reusing the above sequence $\{b_k\}$ we can write the sum as:

$$ \sum_{n=b_1}^{b_2-1} \frac{1}{n \ln n} + \sum_{n=b_2}^{b_3-1} \frac{1}{n \ln n \ln \ln n} + \cdots,$$

where the $k$th summation is

$$S_k := \sum_{n=b_k}^{b_{k+1}-1} \frac{1}{n \ln n \cdots \underbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}_{\text{$k$ times}}\; n}.$$

Let's try to get a lower bound for $S_k$.  By comparison to the integral,

$$S_k > \int_{b_k}^{b_{k+1}} \frac{dx}{x \ln x \cdots \underbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}_{\text{$k$ times}}\; x} = \left.\underbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}_{\text{$k+1$ times}}\; x\,\right|_{x=b_k}^{b_{k+1}} \\
> \underbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}_{\text{$k+1$ times}} \; a_{k+1} - \underbrace{\ln \circ \ln \cdots \circ \ln}_{\text{$k+1$ times}} \; b_k > 1 - (a_k a_{k-1} \cdots a_1)^{-1}.$$

Since $S_k > \tfrac12$, it follows that $\sum_k S_k = \sum_n 1/\text{pln}_2(n)$ diverges.

Comment: The unequality which is after So then... I did not get it.

Comment: @Andrey That just comes from applying the last inequality for the $k+1$th log of $b_k$ to the definition of $\text{pln}_1(b_k)$ which is written in the first equation.  I just expanded out the estimate for the last factor and left everything else the same.

Comment: I get it now! Nice solution!